# Vue - How to dynamically set a grid area name

Tags: css, vue.js, dynamic-binding

I have a list of objects that I loop through and generate inside the template. Those objects need to be positioned differently inside the grid depending on the screen size.

So I would like to use the grid-area property in CSS to define their positions in different screen sizes. But the problem I am facing is that I cannot find how to dynamically define the grid-area name for each of the elements.

I have tried doing to following, but it doesn't work. I have searched online but didn't find any solutions. The title variable is a string that contains the name that needs to be set for the grid-area property.

```
:style="{ title: gridArea }"
```

Comment: so title contains the grid-area name?

Comment: `:style="{ gridArea: xxx }"` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Comment: Yes, it correct. Plus it is a string that doesn't have any spaces. The words are separated by a '_'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a "double name property" you could wrap it in string

`<div class="block" :style="{ 'grid-area': title }">...</div>`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution :D!!

Comment: I can and will do that in 8 mins :)